# Unable to read a csv file name using pandas when the path is command line argument using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, command-line-arguments

I am using python3(python3.6.1 to be specific) for coding.

```
  args = sys.argv
  filename = args[1]
  data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

however it is saying that the file does not exist even though it exists. I see that the filename is encoded as byte string with a b prefix in front of it.

I have also tried the following code.

```
  filename = StringIO(filename)
  data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Now, there is no error. But, I see a empty data frame with columns as the name of the file.

I have run the program using the command.

```
  python id3.py /path/to/filename.csv
```

Could someone help me with this or could someone point me to link which has the answer.

Edit:- There was a problem in the path. The path of the csv file has several spaces. Hence Ubuntu replaced it '%20' due to which python read it as byte string I guess. Hence, it was not able to read the csv file.

When I removed the spaces in the path. python pandas was able to read the csv file.

Thanks

Comment: Can you put the input into the question

Comment: what does `print(filename)` output?

Comment: The print command is giving  /path/to/filename.csv   However, the error it showing is FileNotFounderror: b'/path/to/filename.csv'  does not exist.

Comment: Hey ... Can anybody help me with this question ... I still dont understand why I have got an error !!

Answer (score 0):

Try "file/path/with spaces.csv"

So using quotation marks when you run the script e.g.

```
python script.py "file/path/with spaces.csv"
```